# Add Rows on table in Vf page

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

I am trying to add rows dynamically in my table in vf page. but when I try to do so it overlaps the current row.

here is my controller class:

```
public class BulkPaymentController {


public String message;    
public boolean balanceFlag = false;    
public static boolean selected {get;set;} 
public List<Invoice__c> invoiceList {get;set;}
public String selectedInv {get;set;}
public List<SelectOption>invoicess {get;set;}    

public Map<Integer,InvoiceWrapper> mapSelectInvoiceList {get; set;}

public Integer incrmnt {get;set;}

public BulkPaymentController(){
    incrmnt =0;
    balanceFlag = false;
    invoicess =new List<SelectOption>();
        invoicess.add(new SelectOption('','select'));
    for(Invoice__c inv:[select Id, Name from Invoice__c]){            
        invoicess.add(new SelectOption(inv.id,inv.Name));
    }    

    mapSelectInvoiceList = new Map<Integer,InvoiceWrapper>();
    mapSelectInvoiceList.put(incrmnt,new InvoiceWrapper(false,new Invoice__c(),invoicess));

}
public PageReference addInvoice() {

    incrmnt +=1;

    mapSelectInvoiceList.put(incrmnt,new InvoiceWrapper(false,new Invoice__c(),invoicess));

    return null;
}
public PageReference showInvoices(){        

        for(Invoice__c inv: [select Id, Name,Delivery_Order__c,Delivery_Order__r.Name,Sales_Order__c, Sales_Order__r.Name,Total_Quantity__c,Subtotal_Amount__c,
            Total_Tax_Amount__c,Total_Amount_Inc_Tax__c,Document_Number_Discount_Amount__c,Payment_Invoice_Header__c
            from Invoice__c where id =:selectedInv]) {             


            mapSelectInvoiceList.put(incrmnt,new InvoiceWrapper(false,inv,invoicess));

        }        

return null;
}
public class InvoiceWrapper{
    public List<SelectOption> invoiceslist {get;set;}
    public Boolean selected{get;set;}
    public  Invoice__c inv{get;set;}
    public InvoiceWrapper(Boolean selected1, Invoice__c inv1,List<SelectOption> invoiceslist )
    {
        selected = selected1;
        inv = inv1;
        this.invoiceslist =invoiceslist;            

    }
}
}
```

vf page

```
<apex:outputPanel id="InvoicePanel">
            <div aria-hidden="false" class="slds-section__content" id="expando-unique-id">
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1">
                    <div class="slds-box slds-m-vertical_small">
                        <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer" id= "table">



                            <apex:repeat value="{!mapSelectInvoiceList[incrmnt]}" var="i" >
                                <tr>

                                    <th scope="row" data-label="">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="">
                                            <apex:selectList value="{!selectedInv}" size="1" multiselect="false" id="selectInvoice">

                                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!i.invoiceslist}"/>
                                                 <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!showInvoices}" reRender="InvoicePanel" status="status" >

                                                 </apex:actionSupport>  
                                            </apex:selectList>

                                        </div>
                                    </th>

                                    <th scope="row" data-label="">

                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="">
                                            <a href="/{!i.inv.Sales_Order__c}"
                                               target="_blank">{!i.inv.Sales_Order__r.Name}</a>
                                        </div>

                                    </th>
                                    <th scope="row" data-label="">

                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="">
                                            <a href="/{!i.inv.Delivery_Order__c}"
                                               target="_blank">{!i.inv.Delivery_Order__r.Name}</a>
                                        </div>

                                    </th>
                                    <th scope="row" data-label="">

                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="">
                                                {!i.inv.Total_Quantity__c}
                                        </div>

                                    </th>
                                    <th scope="row" data-label="">

                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="">
                                                {!i.inv.Subtotal_Amount__c}
                                        </div>

                                    </th>
                                    <th scope="row" data-label="">

                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="">
                                                {!i.inv.Total_Tax_Amount__c}
                                        </div>

                                    </th>
                                    <th scope="row" data-label="">

                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="">
                                                {!i.inv.Document_Number_Discount_Amount__c}
                                        </div>

                                    </th>
                                    <th scope="row" data-label="">

                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="">
                                                {!i.inv.Total_Amount_Inc_Tax__c}
                                        </div>

                                    </th>

                                </tr>
                            </apex:repeat>


                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                         <apex:commandButton styleClass="slds-button slds-button--neutral cuf-publisherCancelButton uiButton"
                                action="{!addInvoice}" value="Add Invoice" rerender="InvoicePanel" status="status" 
                                style="margin-top:8px;" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </apex:outputPanel>

    </div>
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use List instead of Map

```
mapSelectInvoiceList = new list< InvoiceWrapper >();

mapSelectInvoiceList.add(new InvoiceWrapper(false,new Invoice__c(),invoicess));
```

---

```
 <apex:repeat value="{!mapSelectInvoiceList}" var="i" >
</apex:repeat>
```

---

```
public PageReference addInvoice() {

    mapSelectInvoiceList.add(new InvoiceWrapper(false,new Invoice__c(),invoicess));

    return null;
}
```

Comment: previously I used the list but its showing duplicate value. that's why I used Map for avoiding duplicate

Comment: Duplicate values means ? When press the add button list add an another row with wrapper values.

Comment: no, when selecting any value from picklist a new row added with duplicate value like 3 times if I selected then 3 rows created with same values.

Comment: I cant understand your Code.When ever u change the picklist, is table should added  with one row ?

Comment: yes, In case if i used list instead of map